# Why was my question locked after edition?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I asked a question. Another user edited it a little. But now I see it's locked for about one hour. Why did it happen? Did I do a bad thing to deserve it?

Comment: The word "edit" is a verb and also a noun e.g "It was **a** useful **edit**" The noun "edition" means a copy for sale, or a version of a text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merely locked it against comments.

I did this because, per usual, within a few moments of the question’s appearance people had already begun answering in comments, something which is not allowed because it breaks the Stack Exchange model.

It is not otherwise locked in any way.

This was the timeline:

- 2023-10-07 17:43:48Z: Question posted.
- 2023-10-07 17:48:00Z: Answer posted in comment.
- 2023-10-07 17:48:36Z: Question edited.
- 2023-10-07 17:48:42Z: Answer in comment deleted.
- 2023-10-07 17:48:54Z: Question locked against comments for an hour.
- 2023-10-07 17:56:25Z: Answer posted in answer.
- 2023-10-07 18:48:56Z: Question unlocked against comments.

Comment: I think you didn't realize it. I didn't mention the question which was about makeup. I meant the question that was about "word". It got locked just minutes after I published it. No comments were added yet at the time. The only thing was that the question got edited a little by a user (and it was a good edition). Thankfully, the question is going to be unlocked a few minutes later. But it's strange for me why it got locked at the first place.

Comment: @SnackExchange Actually, there was an answer posted in a comment. I deleted it. See the timeline I've added to this answer.

Comment: Gods forbid people should learn the simple answer to their simple question without paying homage to the all-consuming Stack Exchange model, which is known not to work in ELU anyway. The hell with the  the Stack Exchange model.